# Google Material Design footer always at the end of the page/ at the bottom

Tags: html, css, material-design, material-design-lite

I am currently facing a problem with Google Material Design Lite. If you take a look at the portfolio example from Google https://getmdl.io/templates/portfolio/about.html and simulate a large screen the footer doesn't stay at the bottom. Is there a solution for this?

I found two similar questions but they were about a sticky footer. I would like to have the footer always at the end of the page and if the page is scrollable, the footer should only visible when you are at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your set a specific `min-height` to `.mdl-grid.portfolio-max-width`,

Just like:

```css
/* When the Navbar is big  */
.mdl-grid.portfolio-max-width {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 316px);
}

/* When the Navbar is small  */
.mdl-grid.portfolio-max-width {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 180px);
}
```

This will work.

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**

Final solution for me:

```css
/* When the Navbar is big  */
.mdl-grid.portfolio-max-width {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 316px);
  display: block;
}

/* When the Navbar is small  */
.mdl-layout__content.header-is-compact > .mdl-grid.portfolio-max-width {
   min-height: calc(100vh - 137px);
}
```

and the following lines to the scroll handler in the MDL JavaScript file:

```js
this.content_.classList.add('header-is-compact');
// the following line to the else if where all the classes get removed
this.content_.classList.remove('header-is-compact');
```

Comment: "and if the page is scrollable, the footer should only visible when you are at the bottom."

Comment: Thank you Saurav Rastogi! As @Goombah pointed out, this will stick the footer always to the bottom of the page, even when you aren't at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @KaRl @Goombah Yes! Its my bad. I've updated my answer, This will work. You just need to change the conditions of `min-height` based on the height of your navbar.

Comment: @SauravRastogi Thanks for the fast reply. It kind of works... The navbar is now at the bottom (not completly but this could be my bad) but the content box is streched now to the bottom without any content. Here is a screenshot: http://imgur.com/a/Tyo7b

Comment: @KaRl I think you are doing something really wrong, if possible can you please attach a link to a fiddle or codepen?

Comment: @SauravRastogi Here is a simple codepen: https://codepen.io/php-freak/pen/Ypwwoq I haven't implemented the version for the compact navbar since it would require some extra JS but you should see the problem now.

Comment: @KaRl I hope that I've understand your problem, therefore I am attaching a link - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ENPKry, please have a look and let me know if it helps? Also this example is only for big navbar.

Comment: @SauravRastogi The problem exists in your version too but I found a fix. Setting display: block; to the .mdl-grid.portfolio-max-width seems to do the trick. The problem was that the inner div was also stretched to the min-width. I will test it out and reply back!

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this is what you want

Add a wrapper class around the existing code. Make the wrapper class relative positioned. get the height of the footer and explicitly declare that. Assign the same value as padding bottom to the wrapper class.

```
.wrapper{
  position:relative;
  padding-bottom:75px;
}
#textbox {
background:rgba(255,255,255,1);
padding:10px;
font-family:arial;
z-index:-1;
box-shadow:0 0 30px rgba(000,000,000,1);
border-radius:10px;
line-height:25px;
display:block;
}


#footer {
background-color:white;
width:50000px;
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
left:0px;
color:black;
font-family:arial;
border:0px;
margin:0px;
display:block;

height:75px;
}
```